# Discordjs: How can I calculate a server or users time since joining?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

### Basicly I want to somehow calculate a server or users time since joining discord.

I was looking at both createdAt and timestamps but I'm not sure how could I get the time either in hour or days format. I want to make an info embed which can show how long the user or guild is on discord. How could I make it? The bot is in JavaScript in Discordjs v13.

Something like:

> "Guild created 6 month and 5 days ago"

> "User joined discord 3 month and 10 days ago"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use discord unix timestamps and [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), so like:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Guild Info")
.setDescription(`**Guild Created:** <t:${Math.floor(message.guild.createdTimestamp / 1000)}:R>`)
await message.channel.send({
embeds: [embed]
})
```

and same for user, hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much, I completly forgot that Discord has that.